# How to change images in grid view as the position changes in android?

Tags: android, image, gridview

I am splitting an image and placing in grid view. On clicking two images in grid view, I want to swap their positions. I am able to change their positions, but the image is not changing. I have used bitmap array for splitting images and placing them in grid view. So how do I change images in grid view by clicking two images? How should I do the swapping of images? How can any one help me?

```
public class Imagepieces extends Activity {
            ArrayList<Bitmap> breakedimages,duplicate;
            GridView g;
            int i=0,temp,temp2,rpos;

            @Override

            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_image);
                breakedimages = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("breaked image");
                duplicate = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(breakedimages);
                Collections.shuffle(duplicate);
                g = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
                g.setAdapter(new CutAdapter(this, breakedimages));
                g.setNumColumns((int) Math.sqrt(breakedimages.size()));
                g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {                
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //=================================================
                        {






                    }
                });
            }

            class CutAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                int iwidth, iheight; 
                Context context;

                public CutAdapter(Imagepieces ipieces, ArrayList<Bitmap> breakedimages) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                    iwidth = breakedimages.get(0).getWidth();
                    iheight = breakedimages.get(0).getHeight();
                    context = ipieces;
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return duplicate.size();
                }

                @Override
                public Object getItem(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return duplicate.get(arg0);
                }

                @Override
                public long getItemId(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return arg0;
                }

                @Override
                public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ImageView i=new ImageView(context);

                    i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(iwidth +5,iheight +5));
                    i.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    i.setImageBitmap(duplicate.get(arg0));

                    return i;
                }

            }
        }
```

How to swap images in the grid view? When i click on the grid view on the first click i have to get position, and second click second position. Then I the images in the two positions and after changing all images i want to compare with the image that has been splitted if both are equal. Then i want to display a toast as game finished. Can anyone help me

Comment: I answered for similar question. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12669463/1443981

Answer (score 0):

In `GridView`,when you want to change a item , all you need is change the `Adapter` which you link to the `GridView`.

For example, swap two item:(GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter)

```
GridAdapter adapter = (GridAdapter)gridv.getAdapter();
String firstItem = adapter.getItem(firstPosition);
String secondItem = adapter.getItem(secondPosition);
adapter.remove(firstItem);
adapter.insert(firstItem, secondPosition);
adapter.remove(secondItem);
adapter.insert(secondItem, firstPosition);
```

You also can change other things in your custom `Adapter` by override the `getView()`.

Comment: i have furnished the complete code see the edit and help me guys please